# Undefined method in Refinery::Blog while search enabling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, refinerycms

I enabled Refinery Search and Refinery Blog extensions in Gemfile and run `rake db:migrate`, `rake db:seed`.

And per Refinery Search instructions file, added the following to `config/application.rb`

```
 config.to_prepare do
   Refinery.searchable_models = [Refinery::Blog]
 end
```

And also created  `app/decorators/models/refinery/blog_decorator.rb` with

```
 Refinery::Blog.class_eval do
   acts_as_indexed :fields => [:title, :body, :custom_teaser]
 end
```

Above example is from: http://refinerycms.com/guides/extending-model

But when I try to run `rails c` or `rails s`, there is an error:

```
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/bismailov/Desktop/my_docs/Inbox/ror/maqolarefinery/app/decorators/models/refinery/blog_decorator.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>': 
undefined method `acts_as_indexed' for Refinery::Blog:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /home/bismailov/Desktop/my_docs/Inbox/ror/maqolarefinery/app/decorators/models/refinery/blog_decorator.rb:1:in `class_eval'
```

What could I be missing here? Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Actually `Refinery::Blog` is a module not a model. Ideally you should use `Refinery::Blog::Post`.